# Getting error in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to get the theme name of website ... and getting problem in a regular expression. If you see there is **angle-child-theme** is url. I need to get that value.

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/angle-child-theme/style.css
```

Currently I'm using this regular expression to get the value

```
$searchfor = $url."/wp-content/themes/";
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/U";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $file, $matches)){
     //Match found
}
```

The problem is on the top of website source code I've below line of code

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/angle/assets/images/favicons/favicon.ico
```

Then my regular expression is getting the value **angle** instead of **angle-child-theme**

**Edit 1:**
Here is the regular expression that I'm using

```
http\:\/\/example\.com\/wp\-content\/themes\/
```

Can anyone help me regarding this regular expression?

https://regex101.com/r/nR2uaj/2

Thanks

Comment: You want to get only the angle-child-theme word from the whole url ?

Comment: yes just angle-child-theme

Comment: theme name would be changed if I use another url ... so for the above example theme name is angle-child-theme ... this could be something else ...

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/nR2uaj/3 (for code sample, see *code generator* section at regex101).

Comment: is there any way to get the previous value of "style.css" ?

Comment: Next time do not forget to use `@`+username in the comment when providing feedback, I was not notified of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to grab a part of a URL that is between `and`, use

```
$re = '@http://example\.com/wp-content/themes/([^/]+)/style\.css@';
```

and get the `$matches[1]` value. Note that the `@` regex delimiter allows keep escaping to the minimum, and all dots that are meant to match literal dots must be escaped. The `([^/]+)` part is a *capturing group* that matches and captures 1 or more characters other than `/` (since `[^...]` is a *negated character class*).

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/WUBRtO):

```
$re = '@http://example\.com/wp-content/themes/([^/]+)/style\.css@';
$str = 'http://example.com/wp-content/themes/angle/assets/images/favicons/favicon.ico\nhttp://example.com/wp-content/themes/angle-child-theme/style.css';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you found my answer helpful, please also consider upvoting it (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem:

Here is the regular expression that will get my required value:

```
/http\:\/\/example\.com\/wp\-content\/themes\/([^\/]+)\/style.css/
```

Comment: `style.css` matches `style-css`, too. Do you want to say that there must be `/style.css` after your desired value?